# python file is not executing through ajax even though getting confirmation

Tags: python

Python code:

```
f = open('myfile', 'w')
f.write('Hello \n')
f.close()
```

demo.html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url:'hello.py',
            type:'POST',
            success : function() {
                $("#msg").text('successfully called python');
            },
            error:function(){
                $("#msg").text('there was an error ');
            }
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
 <p id="msg">print something</p>
 <input type="button" id='demo' onClick="foo();" value="call hello.py">
</html>
```

If Python is executed through terminal, it is creating my file and writing `hello` to it, but when I call Python file through html-> ajax I get a message saying Python was called, but the `myfile` output file is not created.

Comment: Where are you attempting to create the file?  Does your web server have write access to that location?

Comment: You can't call python scripts from js like that. you have to create a [web server](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) that can execute python code and return a response. and then you can call that endpoint via ajax.